# Problem reading an byte array into an object after being decoded from a string.

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a byte array to a string using Base64 for as3.

Here is my code

```
public function Serialize(vector:Vector.<Action>):String
    {
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var serialized:String = "";

        registerClassAlias("Action", Action);

        try { bytes.writeObject(vector); trace("Unserialized bytes:\n" + bytes + "\n"); }
        catch (e:Error) { trace("Writing object Failed!!\n" + e); }

        bytes.position = 0;
        bytes.compress();
        trace("Compressed bytes:\n" + bytes + "\n");

        return Base64.encode(bytes);
    }

public function Deserialize(serializedString:String):Vector.<Action>
    {
        var deserialized:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var deserializedObj:Object = new Object();
        var newVector:Vector.<Action> = new Vector.<Action>();

        try { deserialized = Base64.decode(serializedString); trace("Deserialized bytes:\n" + deserialized + "\n"); }
        catch (e:Error) { trace("Decoding Failed!!\n" + e); }

        deserialized.position = 0;
        deserialized.uncompress();
        trace("Uncompressed bytes:\n" + deserialized + "\n");

        try { deserializedObj = deserialized.readObject(); trace("Moving bytes into an object" + deserializedObj); }
        catch (e:Error) { trace("Reading Object Failed!!\n" + e); }

        for each(var a:Action in deserializedObj)
        {
            trace(a);
            newVector.push(a);
        }

        return newVector;
    }
```

I tested this and serializing works fine, but

```
Reading Object Failed!!
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on System::Action(). Expected 2, got 0.
```

is the error I get after calling `deserializedObj = deserialized.readObject();` 
Should I be get that error if I'm just trying to put this into an object?  I'm not trying to put it into an action class object yet, but if it is then the action it's getting doesn't have parameters that were originally inside.

Comment: Do you always call Serialize before Deserialize? If you don't, then registerClassAlias won't be called before deserialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Action` has a constructor that takes two parameters (without defaults). `readObject` apparently [can't handle](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=796980) constructing objects with non-default constructors.

Change `Action` so that its constructor parameters have defaults and see if that helps.

Comment: This worked. I figured it was something like that as I was posting the question but I've been working frustrated and never thought that would be the actually problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that error System:Action
The only thing that I see that could be an issue.

try moving

```
deserialized.uncompress();
```

above

```
deserialized.position = 0;
```

Comment: Why? If the position isn't already at 0, it should be *before* uncompressing. Otherwise you'll get an interesting decompression error.

Comment: Also, there's no point in setting the position to 0 after calling `uncompress`, since the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#uncompress()) say this should be done automatically.

Comment: Like I said was a shot in the dark. But doesn't matter since its all fixed.